# Linking Excel Workbooks

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I work for a large agency and created a spreadsheet for employees to track time spent throughout the day working on a series of duty assignments. I designed a separate workbook for each employee where their daily totals are maintained for each month, and each month is featured on it's own tab.  These workbooks are saved in sub-folders based on the unit the employee is assigned to. And finally, I'm linking the monthly totals to a master workbook compiling all the data for the employees as a whole.

At times, it is necessary to reassign one or more employees from one unit to another.  When that happens, I move the monthly totals workbook from one sub-folder to another sub-folder, reflecting the change in his/her duty station. There are reasons why this is advantageous. But when the workbook is moved to another folder, the links are broken.  Does anyone know how to prevent that?  If not, the alternative will be to save all the workbooks to a single folder which presents a different issue for me unrelated to this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the workbook you want to move
- open all other workbooks that have formulas, references or links to that source workbook.
- Now use Save As to save the source workbook to a new folder.
- Save all the other workbooks
- close the source workbook
- the formulas, references or links will now use the new location
- delete the original source workbook.

Comment: Excellent.  Worked exactly as described.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please accept my post as the answer as described in the [Tour]